# Kafka offset is set to -1000

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

My Kafka Consumer says the following:

```
[TopicPartition{topic=my-topic,partition=0,offset=-1000,error=None}]
```

Whenever I run poll(), it returns `None`.

I want the offset to be set to the last consumed message. If I manually set the `offset=0`, anytime I re-start the consumer, all messages will be re-read -- I only want to consume messages from the last offset.

Why is my offset set to -1000?

How can I have kafka manage the offset for me instead of it always being -1000?

What does a -1000 offset mean, it seems pretty invalid.

Comment: Why manually seek to 0? Sounds like you want to `seekToEnd` if you literally want the latest available offset. If you want the last committed, you post needs more information about the consumer properties and if you're committing offsets at all

Answer (score 0):

I would think of 3 things:

1. Could you please confirm if the consumer received messages at any point of time?
2. Please try below cli command to see the lag of your consumer:

```
kafka-consumer-groups --bootstrap-server <> --group <consumer-group>  --command-config <kafka_client.properties-path> --describe
```

3. How are you committing the offsets in your consumer code?(check enable.auto.commit property; if true kafka client should commit periodically)